# AVPlayer strange behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I use an avplayer instance to play a movie that plays forward and backward, depending on the device's roll. I use the rate at 1/-1 for that. Besides some lagging when rewinding, I have an awkward effect every some seconds. It seems as the movie is kind of reloaded and zoomed back into the view.
Observing status, rate and duration values show no additional execution of anything, memory consumption is stable, initialisation is not repeated either.
I didn't find anything, but does the avplayer has something like a sleep mode? auto reload? 
Any ideas at what to look into would be much appreciated.

Comment: are u changing playerLayer  fillMode or videoGravity ?

Comment: nope. actually, it's a very reduced prototype. Actually, I don't do much of anything besides loading, playing and changing rate at this point. I don't think, it's anything that is triggered in the code directly.